# Upload new sketch to openCR1.0 when connected to SBC

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, opencr, raspberrypi, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Kinetic on a Turtlebot Burger 3. It's using the basic turtlebot packages which can be found on ROBOTIS.

I'm looking for a practical way to upload a new sketch from the Arduino IDE to the openCR1.0 board, without disconnecting it from the Raspberry Pi SBC and connecting it directly to the remote PC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321612/upload-new-sketch-to-opencr1.0-when-connected-to-sbc/) by [Ocean-11](https://answers.ros.org/users/40985/ocean-11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have the Arduino IDE installed on the Raspberry pi then you can SSH into the pi and compile and upload from the command line.

I've never done it but it is documented here:

https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/CommandLine/

here is another answer I found:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37534.0

good luck

---

Originally posted by [tomsepe](https://answers.ros.org/users/39314/tomsepe/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ocean-11](https://answers.ros.org/users/40985/ocean-11/) on 2019-04-28**:
Thanks tomsepe for the great resources!

Managing the openCR code from the SBC is rather annoying, but it is far better than switching between SBC/remote computer serial lines every time I want to modify a line in the openCR firmware, so I will definitely try it ..

Hopefully this infrastructure would be supported some day, so it would be possible to upload the code directly from the remote computer virtual machine ..